# How do I know which Mosh Client I am?

Tags: ssh, kill, mosh

When I try `who`, I frequently see output such as this:

```
username  pts/0        2015-10-09 04:48 (mosh [2680])
username  pts/2        2015-10-12 00:04 (75.139.11.119 via mosh [12364])
username  pts/6        2015-10-12 00:10 (75.139.11.119 via mosh [9728])
```

Where my username is logged into several sessions. Unfortunately I do not know which one I am currently using. Is there a way to tell so that if I `kill` the mosh `PID`, I don't kill my own session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`tty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) command will tell you which pseudo-terminal session you are running. And that can distinguish which line is yours.

Comment: In this case that returns `/dev/pts/3 ` which is not even one if the listed ones. Does that make sense?

Comment: I should clarify. I am using tmux, so it returns that value. However, exiting tmux returns `/dev/pts/6`.  
Do you know of a way to get the right shell identifier no matter what?

Comment: I'm afraid of this question wandering around a bit. If you are running `tmux`, then do a `ps $(pidof tmux)`  or `ps -ef | grep [t]mux` and that shows you the processes and tty that are running tmux.

Comment: @Startec Yes, it makes sense that `tmux` reports a different pseudo terminal. The tmux process forks another process. That process in turn forks a shell for each window, and each shell has its own pseudo tty. `pstree` or, better, a dynamic process tree program called [xps](http://motif-pstree.sourceforge.net/) will show the process tree structure.